# Replace PowerMockito.verifyStatic by Mockito.verify on Android

Tags: java, android, mockito, powermock, powermockito

Mockito seems to get more and more of PowerMockito's features.

When I updated to

```
        junitVersion = "4.13.2"
        mockitoVersion = "4.2.0"
        hamcrestVersion = "2.2"
        powermockVersion = "2.0.9"
```

tests are failing.

So I am trying to get rid of PowerMokito.

Problem is there is no **verifyStatic**
https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito/latest/org/powermock/api/mockito/PowerMockito.html#verifyStatic-java.lang.Class-org.mockito.verification.VerificationMode-

https://github.com/telekom/SmartCredentials-SDK-android/blob/develop/SmartCredentials_aOS/camera/src/test/java/de/telekom/smartcredentials/camera/views/presenters/CameraViewPresenterTest.java#L66

How do I replace

```
PowerMockito.verifyStatic(ApiLoggerResolver.class);
```

Do I just write

```
Mockito.verify(ApiLoggerResolver.class);
```

or do I have to do a

```
        MockedStatic<ApiLoggerResolver> apiLoggerResolverMockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(ApiLoggerResolver.class);

        Mockito.verify(apiLoggerResolverMockedStatic);
```

Comment: Neither of those - you need to specify the static method to be verified. https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#static_mocks

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it.

Although, I seems that this does not work on Android at all.

```
Mockito's inline mock maker supports static mocks based on the Instrumentation API.
You can simply enable this mock mode, by placing the 'mockito-inline' artifact where you are currently using 'mockito-core'.
Note that Mockito's inline mock maker is not supported on Android.
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not work on Android which I need and what triggered this question.

```
Mockito's inline mock maker supports static mocks based on the Instrumentation API.
You can simply enable this mock mode, by placing the 'mockito-inline' artifact where you are currently using 'mockito-core'.
Note that Mockito's inline mock maker is not supported on Android.
```

I am using mockito-core but it seems that mockito-inline does not work on Android. Maybe the next version is going to support Android?!